# How to display a column from a multiple tables in a SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, multiple-columns, toad

I am attempting to display a column from one of 3 tables I have in my query, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work properly. No matter what I try, it doesn't seem to work. It seems easy, but maybe I am missing something really simple. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT hpg.id_number,
     hpg.id_description,
     COUNT (hdd.number_of_games) games,
     SUM (NVL (price, 0)) total,
     SUM (number_of_food) food
--I tried adding column here, but nothing seemed to work
FROM (SELECT number_of_games, price, prints
        FROM (hopeful_dog_hops)
       WHERE status = 'Done') hdd,
     (SELECT SUM (number_of_food) number_of_food, number_of_games
          FROM hot_digity_dog
      GROUP BY number_of_games) hdd1,
     (SELECT id_description, sort_types, id_number
        FROM (hot_pick_games)
       WHERE disabled = 'TRUE' AND viewable_type = 'OK') hpg
WHERE hdd.prints(+) = hpg.id_number
     AND hdd.number_of_games = hdd1.number_of_games
GROUP BY hpg.id_description, hpg.id_number, sort_types
ORDER BY sort_types
```

This huge query displays these columns:

```
ID_NUMBER    ID_DESCRIPTION    GAMES    TOTAL    FOOD
```

I need to add one more column:

```
TEST
```

from the hot_digity_dog table.

Don't worry so much about the names of everything, but I just need to figure out how exactly I can get another column to display in the query. I tried adding TEST to the first SELECT statement, but it gave me an error saying: "TEST:invalid identifier."

I know the query works (without the added TEST part, so it can't be an error in the query). It has to be something with the new added part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the query with the new column:

```
SELECT hpg.id_number,
     hpg.id_description,
     COUNT (hdd.number_of_games) games,
     SUM (NVL (price, 0)) total,
     SUM (number_of_food) food,
     hdd.TEST
FROM (SELECT number_of_games, price, prints
        FROM (hopeful_dog_hops)
       WHERE status = 'Done') hdd,
     (SELECT SUM (number_of_food) number_of_food, number_of_games
          FROM hot_digity_dog
      GROUP BY number_of_games) hdd1,
     (SELECT id_description, sort_types, id_number
        FROM (hot_pick_games)
       WHERE disabled = 'TRUE' AND viewable_type = 'OK') hpg
WHERE hdd.prints(+) = hpg.id_number
     AND hdd.number_of_games = hdd1.number_of_games
GROUP BY hpg.id_description, hpg.id_number, sort_types
ORDER BY sort_types
```

And here is what the column headers should look like:

```
ID_NUMBER    ID_DESCRIPTION    GAMES    TOTAL    FOOD    TEST
```

Comment: Please show the query where you added the additional column.

Comment: try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: You never select the TEST column in the hdd query.  Select it there, along with `number_of_games, price, prints` and I suspect it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing the test column in the hdd query:

```
SELECT hpg.id_number,
     hpg.id_description,
     COUNT (hdd.number_of_games) games,
     SUM (NVL (price, 0)) total,
     SUM (number_of_food) food,
     hdd.TEST
FROM (SELECT number_of_games, price, prints, TEST
        FROM (hopeful_dog_hops)
       WHERE status = 'Done') hdd,
     (SELECT SUM (number_of_food) number_of_food, number_of_games
          FROM hot_digity_dog
      GROUP BY number_of_games) hdd1,
     (SELECT id_description, sort_types, id_number
        FROM (hot_pick_games)
       WHERE disabled = 'TRUE' AND viewable_type = 'OK') hpg
WHERE hdd.prints(+) = hpg.id_number
     AND hdd.number_of_games = hdd1.number_of_games
GROUP BY hpg.id_description, hpg.id_number, sort_types
ORDER BY sort_types
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not selecting from `hot_digity_dog` in the outer query. You select from an AGGREGATE subquery based on that table - a subquery you aliased as `hdd1`. So, it is not clear **how** you want to add that column. Is `test` completely determined by `number_of_games`? If it is, then you can add `test` to the `select` and `group by` clauses of the aggregate subquery, and then you can select it in the outer query.

If `test` is not determined by `number_of_games`, do you want to sum `number_of_food` as grouped by `number_of_games` **and** `test`? If so, again, add `test` to `select` and `group by` in the subquery (but the results will be different from grouping by `number_of_games` alone).

If `test` is not determined by `number_of_games`, you want to group by `number_of_games` for the sum, but you want to show `test` anyway, you may want to use **analytic** `sum()` rather than aggregate `sum()`.

This is only a small example to prove to you that what you posted is not nearly enough to allow us to help you. Please provide (much) more detail - by editing the original question, NOT in Comments.